# How to make a user-defined type initialize *exactly* like a built-in type?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, initialization, value-initialization

I would like to make a type that wraps a numeric type (and provides additional functionality).
Furthermore, I need the number and the wrapper to be **both implicitly convertible** to each other.

So far I have:

```
template<class T>
struct Wrapper
{
    T value;
    Wrapper() { }
    Wrapper(T const &value) : value(value) { }
    // ... operators defined here ...
};
```

It's *almost* good, but it doesn't *quite* behave the same as a built-in type:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned int x1, x2 = unsigned int();
    Wrapper<unsigned int> y1, y2 = Wrapper<unsigned int>();

    std::cerr << x1       << std::endl;  // uninitialized, as expected
    std::cerr << y1.value << std::endl;  // uninitialized, as expected

    std::cerr << x2       << std::endl;  // zero-initialized, as expected
    std::cerr << y2.value << std::endl;  // uninitialized!?!
}
```

Is there any way for me to design the `Wrapper` such that statements like

```
Wrapper<unsigned int> y2 = Wrapper<unsigned int>();
```

initialize the `value` inside, *but **without*** forcing statements like

```
Wrapper<unsigned int> y1;
```

to also do the same?

In other words, is it possible to make a type that behaves **exactly** the same as a built-in type in terms of initialization?

Comment: If you're willing to require a change on the user's side rather than in the class definition, you could use `Type(boost::initialized_value)` instead of `Type()`.

Comment: @aschepler: I'm confused, what's `Type` in your comment?

Comment: A template parameter, perhaps.  Or just a typedef for `unsigned int` or `Wrapper<unsigned int>`, etc.

Comment: I changed my answer, as dyp points out you can actually achieve what you want by using `= default` with the default constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Okay, so as dyp points out, I and everyone else was wrong. You can achieve what you want to do by `= default` with the default constructor:

```
 Wrapper() = default ;
           ^^^^^^^^^
```

This works because without an initializer you obtain the same behavior I outline before but when you use value initialization the behavior changes as outlined in paragraph *8*:

> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type **without a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then the object is zero-initialized** and, if T has a non-trivial default constructor, default-initialized;

**Original Answer**

I don't think there is a way to make this work the way you would like. Class types act differently that builtin types we can see this from the draft standard section  `8.5` *Initializers* paragraph *12* which says (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> If **no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized**; if no initialization is performed, an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration has indeterminate value. [ Note: Objects with static or thread storage duration are zero-initialized, see 3.6.2. —end note ]

and we can see this has different results for classes than built-in types from paragraph *7* which says:

> To default-initialize an object of type T means:

and includes the following bullets:

> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) **class type (Clause 9), the default constructor for T is called** (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
>
> — if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
>
> — **otherwise, no initialization is performed.**

and if we look at paragraph *11* for the second case `Wrapper<unsigned int>()` it says:

> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), **shall be value-initialized.**

and then back to paragraph *8*:

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) **class type** (Clause 9) with either no default constructor (12.1) or a default constructor that is user-provided or deleted, then the object **is default-initialized;** [...]

So we end up with the same behavior.

Both *Praetorian* and *aschepler* gave you options that work slightly differently but appear to achieve the behavior you would like just not with the same syntax.

Comment: But a default constructor does not necessarily initialize its members.

Comment: @aschepler but then the value initialzation case does not work.

Comment: So what if you default the default ctor? Value-initialization like `auto x = Wrapper<int>();` will zero-initialize the object, whereas default-initialization like `Wrapper<int> x;` will default-initialize it.

Comment: @dyp hmmm, I don't see that, as far as I can tell section `12 p 6` from `N3485` doesn't say that but maybe I am mis-reading. If you can point me to the section then I will happily update my answer.

Comment: `auto x = Wrapper<int>();` (the rhs) is value-initialization [dcl.init]/11. The second bullet in [dcl.init]/8 says "if `T` is a [..] non-union class type without a user-provided [..] default constructor" which is the case if the default ctor is defaulted. The object will be zero-initialized, which means recursive zero-initialization of all subobjects (even for class types). `Wrapper<int> x;` is default-initialization [dcl.init]/12. The first bullet in [dcl.init]/7 says, the default ctor is called. The defaulted default-ctor will perform default-init of all subobjects, which means no init here.

Comment: @dyP I see what you are saying now, let me update my answer. Thank you for pointing that out, I learned something new today.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Oooh wow, I didn't see this one coming... I guess it's C++11-only but it's better than nothing! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any way to achieve what you're looking for. As soon as you define a default constructor for a class that will be called whether you provide or omit parentheses when defining an instance of the class.

You can get kinda close by declaring the following constructor; the variable definition will require an empty pair of braces to achieve value initialization.

```
Wrapper(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> /*unused*/) : value() {}

auto y3 = Wrapper<unsigned int>({}); // y3.value will be value initialized
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1239a846b719d38d)

But I'd sooner drop the requirement for implicit conversion to `Wrapper`, and keep the class an aggregate, than implement the solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not that I can think of. C++ implicitly converts `class_type name` to call the default constructor. You would have to make the default constructor do what you'd expect an un-initialized primitive type to do.

Comment: You may be right that it's impossible, but I think your explanation of why it is impossible may in fact be wrong.

Comment: I guess I simplified. As long as you haven't explicitly *not* defined a default constructor (by defining any other constructor and not defining a zero-argument one), it will happen. Shafik's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the user-provided constructor, you can leave the member uninitialized when default-constructing, or value-initialize the wrapper and in doing so zero-initialize its storage (and therefore its member):

```
unsigned int x1, x2 {}; // One uninitialized, one value-initialized
Wrapper<unsigned int> y1, y2 {}; // Ditto
```

You can still set the value during construction via aggregate-initialization:

```
Wrapper<int> z {42};
```

At any rate, this is largely unnecessary; uninitialized values are rarely useful except to introduce subtle, difficult-to-reproduce bugs. I would recommend value-initializing the member either in the default constructor or in the member declaration.

Comment: Uninitialized values are pretty darn useful. They can make array allocations O(1) time instead of O(n).

Comment: @Mehrdad Zero-initializing an array may be O(n), but with a very low constant factor. That's not to say it's _never_ a problem, but in my experience it's quite rare; how often do you write code that repeatedly allocates a large array in a tight loop? This smells like premature optimization, and there are ways to avoid the initialization cost once you've profiled, without sacrificing the well-behavedness of the common case.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I believe you have absolutely ***zero*** evidence that this is premature optimization.

Comment: @Mehrdad I always zero-initialize my arrays, and it has _never_ caused performance issues. That's all the evidence I need not to go polluting my program with uninitialized values just because it might spend a few fewer microseconds zeroing out memory. Without empirical evidence that the initialization negatively impacts performance, leaving values or arrays uninitialized because it seems like it should be faster is _by definition_ a premature optimization.

Comment: No, what I'm telling you is that there is *nothing* in my question that even *hints* that **my** optimization is premature, or that I don't have empirical evidence this is necessary. In other words, you're assuming with zero evidence that you know my constraints better than I do. Piece of advice: when you don't have any evidence to believe you know people's constraints better than themselves, *don't assume so*.

Comment: And *just for your information*, leaving some arrays uninitialized in my program gives me a 10% running time boost (from 7.3 to 6.5 seconds), which I believe is worth it. (It's also worth noting that it drops the peak working set from 3.3 GB to 3.0 GB, which I'm not exactly unhappy about.)

Comment: @Mehrdad I did not assume that you hadn't made the appropriate measurements, nor did I assume that you _had_. Without knowing that you had found the optimization to be applicable, a footnote on the downsides and uncommon applicability of the technique after the answer to the question seemed perfectly relevant. It was meant as helpful _general_ advice about performing this optimization prematurely, not an accusation that _you_ had performed it prematurely. I'm sorry if I didn't make that clear.