# Why does "ctor() = default" change behavior when other constructors are present?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constructor, default-constructor, visual-c++-2013

Why does

```
struct wrapper
{
    explicit wrapper(void *);
    wrapper() = default;
    int v;
};

int main() { return wrapper().v; }  // You should run this in Debug mode
```

return `0xCCCCCCCC`, whereas

```
struct wrapper { wrapper() = default; int v; };
int main() { return wrapper().v; }
```

and

```
struct wrapper { int v; };
int main() { return wrapper().v; }
```

both return `0`?

Comment: when you add the non-=default constructor, the type is no longer an aggregate.  I'm sure that's playing into this, not sure how though.  I doubt you're guaranteed that it's 0 in either case.

Comment: @RyanHaining: Are you sure? If so then it seems weird because it would imply the only time you could use `= default` would be when there are no other constructors present, which seems pointless...

Comment: The `=default` is going to give back the default constructor, but `v` is unintialized in both cases.  With gcc I get 0 even in the first case, but it's all just by chance.

Comment: @RyanHaining: Do you still get zero in the first case with GCC if you explicitly declare the constructor as `wrapper() { }` (i.e. avoid initializing `v`)? (Don't forget to do both of these experiments in debug mode with no optimizations.)

Comment: in that case I don't, no, I get a huge value as well.  I think I'm mistaken about the 0 guarantees actually.  I'm looking at the rules atm

Comment: @RyanHaining: Yeah I think so too :) I'm pretty sure `= default` gives you the same default constructor that would've been implicitly declared if the user hadn't declared any constructors, but feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67646/discussion-between-ryan-haining-and-mehrdad).

Comment: What standard, if any, is VS-2013 supposed to implement? This kind of thing *might* change subtly between c++03, c++11 and c++14.

Comment: @juanchopanza: C++11 with some aspects of C++14: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-the-visual-c-compiler-november-2013-ctp.aspx
Although I don't see why it would change from C++11 to C++14...

Comment: Maybe it's [this bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/917875)?

Comment: (For the rest of you, this question is very related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/22265255/541686)

Comment: @dyp: Looks related but I can't tell if it's the same.

Comment: It seems that deleting the converting constructor makes VS behave reasonably again. I suspect it might have to do with the part about "no user-provided constructors" in the value-initialization specification. Anyway, I'd say it's a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During *value-initialization*, if `T` is a class type without a user-provided or deleted default-constructor, then the object is *zero-initialized* (§8.5/8.2). This is indeed the case with `wrapper`.

Your first example matches the third case for zero-initialization (§8.5/6.1, emphasis mine)

> > — if `T` is a scalar type (3.9), the object is initialized to the value obtained by converting the integer literal
> >     `0` (zero) to `T`;
> >
> > — **if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, each non-static data member and each base-class sub-object is zero-initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;**
> >
> > — if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) union type, the object’s first non-static named data member is zero-initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;
> >
> > — if T is an array type, each element is zero-initialized
> >
> > — if T is a reference type, no initialization is performed

So in your first example, `v` should be zero-initialized. This looks like a bug.

In your second and third example you no longer have a user-provided constructor, but you do have a default-constructor that isn't user-provided or deleted so your example still falls into the third case for zero-initialization, which is to zero-initialize each non-static data member. VS is correct there.

Comment: There's been a defect in the C++11 Standard. If you read the IS, it says "without a user-provided constructor", which lacks the crucial "default".

Comment: @Mehrdad :D oh, that has become ambiguous recently - I'm referring to the International Standard. See also: http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1301

Comment: @dyp Would the redaction affect the answer?

Comment: @dyp: LOL if meant what I think you meant that was pretty funny. And I see haha, thanks for the link.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I'm not entirely sure what you're referring to. A language-lawyer could argue that VS is behaving perfectly conforming, since the first wrapper does have a user-provided constructor (the converting ctor). -- edit: hm, *user-provided* is only defined for special member functions..

Comment: This exact behavior is noted in the code snippet in [CWG 1368](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1368), resolved in the same change @dyp linked.

Comment: @T.C. What I don't quite understand is *how* the C++11 text mandates this behaviour. Does *user-provided constructor* also match the non-default ctor? It's not a *special member function*..

Answer (score 4):

This does appear to be a bug in MSVC.  In all three cases `wrapper` has no user-provided default constructor, so initialization with `wrapper()` invokes:

(All citations from [n3690](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf))

> (8.5/11) An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be value-initialized.

(thanks to dyp), this will result in zero-intialization of `int v`

Initialization then refers us to the rule:

> (8.5/8) if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and the semantic constraints for default-initialization are checked.

The zero initialization rules state:

> (8.5/6) if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, each non-static data member and each base-class subobject is zero-initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits

`int v` being a data member of `wrapper` is zero initialiazed itself according to:

> (8.5/6) if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is initialized to the value obtained by converting the integer literal 0 (zero) to T

Which is not the behavior you observe.

Comment: It'd be nice if you could explain why GCC and Clang are going through the extra trouble to value-initialize everything if you think VC++ is correct in not doing so.

Comment: @Mehrdad I reversed everything

Comment: @dyp this is the subtlest c++ point I've ever (been pushed to) hit.